# Check about whether my application is making use of wifi in ios

Tags: ios, ios5, wifi

I need to develop a application where i need to get information or notification whenever my application makes use of internet. I get the code to get notification when wifi status changes but not getting how to get notification when my application try to access the wifi. Any help regarding this is really appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with knowing when your application trying to use wifi? You coded it. Can you explain more?

Comment: i have explained it clearly in the last comment of this blog please refer it and help me.

Comment: And as you can see, cleary, I asked this way before your comment explaining it. So, as your answer seemed kind of rude my participation ends here. BTW this is not a blog.

Comment: sorry i am new to this site so i may not know the proper way of responding here. But my intension is not to reply rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use reachability class provide by the apple. And register for notification.

```
self.reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"hostName"];
    [reachability startNotifier];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityStatusChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: heh this will give notification when the wifi status changed. But i need notification whenever my app try to access the internet.

Comment: Can you explain your context a bit?.

Comment: if i try to open any feature related to internet in my application i need a notification like you are making use of internet. how to achieve this

Comment: When you need an internet related feature for your app, you would have written some code to connect internet right?. When such a method is called you can bring up an alert view. I do not know any resource that checks information flow like you ask.

Comment: Actually I developed a application to get the info of whichever application comes to foreground. So i need to add this feature to my application about every foreground placing app. So I am searching the way for this. Anyways thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) to accomplish that :)

Comment: I think you people dint understand exactly about my requirement. I don't want notification when wifi state changes. I just want to get notification when my application try to access internet. Say for example when i try to open the browser through my application i need a notification like "you are using internet feature". I hope this clearly states my requirement.